# mongodump 3.2.1 positional arguments not allowed

Tags: mongodb

trying mongodump with following options and get "positional arguments not allowed"

```
mongodump --host=hostname --port=27017 --db=db --out=/path --oplog --gzip
```

tried `mongodump -h hostname -d dbname` and that works

What does the message

> positional arguments not allowed

mean?

Answer (score 9):

You got the syntax wrong in the first one.  You need to remove the `=` sign. [See documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/).

```
mongodump --host hostname --port 27017 --db db --out /path --oplog --gzip
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be entirely correct. I'm getting `-h, --host=<hostname>` syntax when running `mongodump --help on Linux`, and it was proven to work on Windows, too (v3.2). I've got this error when accidentally supplying wrong arguments.

Comment: Oddly enough, some of the arguments need a "=" before the value and some of them just need a space. I was putting a space after "--archive" which was wrong for me. The archive, is one of the ones that needs an equals. So the best actual answer is for everyone to look at the documentation on every argument before trying it, to see if it's a space or an equals that's required.

Answer (score 1):

```
mongodump -d<dbname> -o <backUpPath>
```

like this:

```
mongodump -d projectdb -o /Users/zhangzhanqi/Desktop/backup_mongo/aaa
```

Comment: Making detailed explanations will be more beneficial for everyone.

Comment: sorry, I have been aware of this problem

Answer (score 0):

The syntax has been changed to replacement of `=` with space character in front of the argument names. To clear the point with a descriptive answer, I put two general forms with **long argument** and **short argument** names.

**Long parameter form:**

`mongodump --host hostname --port 27017 --db db --out /path --oplog --gzip`

**Short parameter form:**

`mongodump -h hostname -p 27017 -d db -o /path --oplog --gzip`

You can find more explanation and examples in the following link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/